# Limit of a sequence involving floor function

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions, percolation

I am reading an article, and in a certain point I need to estimate the following limit

$$\xi_p=\lim \limits_{k \to +\infty} \frac{k}{\lfloor\frac{k}{n}\rfloor+1},$$

where $n \ge 1$ is fixed.

The claim of the author is that $\xi_p < n$. I can have an intuition why that's true, but I can't formalize this. The best bound I can reach is
$$\frac{k}{\lfloor\frac{k}{n}\rfloor+1} <\frac{k}{\frac{k-1}{n}+1}=\frac{kn}{k+n-1}$$

Therefore $\xi_p \le n$. What am I missing?
 Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I am adding some context. Maybe I am making a mistake in a point before that.

The article is about an upper bound for the percoletion correlation lenght on $\mathbb{Z}^d$. In a certain point, the authors reach to the bound 
 $$P_p[0 \leftrightarrow \partial\Lambda_k] \le e^{-\lfloor k/n \rfloor-1}$$

where $\partial\Lambda_k$ is the boundary of the box centered on the origin with width $k$.

Just after that ist he claim that this implies that the correlation lenght  $\xi_p$ is strictly less than $n$, and this is what I am trying to proof.

Since 
$$\xi_p= \lim \limits_{k \to +\infty} -\frac{k}{\log P_p[0 \leftrightarrow \partial\Lambda_k]}$$

and using the bound found earlier for the relevant probability, I arrived on the limit in the beginning of the question.

[Here is the article in question](https://www.ihes.fr/~duminil/publi/2019quantitativeGM.pdf). The relevant bound is on page 6. I guess I am makin a very dumb error, but i can't found it out.

Comment: Is $k$ non-negative?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy Yes, it is.

Comment: You sure it's the floor function?

Comment: The result holds for the ceiling function.

Comment: If $n=1$ then the limit is $1$ so the strict relation cannot hold for $n=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether that is the floor function or the ceiling function, the limit is $n$, by a simple application of the [sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem):

$$ k/n < \lfloor k/n \rfloor + 1 \le \lceil k/n \rceil + 1 \le k/n + 2 $$

So

$$ n = {k \over k/n} > {k \over \lfloor k/n \rfloor + 1} \ge {k \over \lceil k/n \rceil + 1} \ge {k \over k/n + 2} = {kn \over k + 2n}$$

But the limit of the last term

$$\lim_{k \to +\infty} {kn \over k+2n} = n$$

So all the limits are equal to $n$.

BTW it is true that for any finite $k$, the expression is $< n$ (whether that function is floor or ceiling).  But that does not at all mean the limit $< n$.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the floor function, then the claim is incorrect, as
$$\frac{k}{\lfloor\frac{k}{n}\rfloor+1}\geq \frac{k}{\frac{k}{n}+1} = \frac{kn}{k+n} \to  n \text{ as } k\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't hold for the floor function.If it were the ceiling function, then,

$\lceil k/n\rceil \geq k/n$. So,$1+\lfloor k/n\rfloor \geq 1+ k/n> k/n$. This implies,

$n/k > \frac{1}{1+\lceil k/n\rceil}$ which gives $n> \frac{k}{1+\lceil k/n\rceil}$ (assuming $k$ is non-negative). Leting $k \rightarrow \infty$, you get the desired result for $n>1$.

Comment: Isn't $\lfloor k/n \rfloor$ the greatest integer less or equal than $k/n$? It shouldn't be $\lfloor k/n \rfloor \le k/n$?

Comment: It can't be the floor function & edited my previous answer.